# Overlapping meshes

Tags: mesh

I'm sort of new to blender.
I'm having problems with overlapping meshes. when I render, the strange blackish effect is observed.
Specifically, I'm trying to model a 6-point star ("star of david"). e.g., see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Star_of_David.svg

I start with a non filled triangle, duplicate it and scaling it down in edit-mode, and then creating 3 quad faces. I duplicate in object mode, rotate 180deg around the z axis, and do a bool union.
However, in the resulting object, the vertices don't land on the intersection of the triangle edges, so I can't delete the overlapping regions.

How can this be done?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi JohnDope so it takes some time for me to answer so follow these steps and images...

1. Make a **circle with 3 points (NO FILL)** and then **extrude it in edit mode** using "E" and "S" to the desired width like here...

[image]

2. Make a **copy of this triangle** in object mode using "SHIFT + D" and **rotate it 180degrees** using "R" like here...

[image]

...in fact now You have two options. You can **slightly** move the 2nd object up or down so there will be **no overlap** and then select both triangles and join them using "CTRL + J" and You will be good beause of using a really slight move (0.01mm for example - the object will look good enough).

Second option is to edit it properly and **thats the one we do now ;).**

3. Go to the object mode, select 2nd triangle and move it up. Then select 1st triangle **with the 2nd still selected** so use "SHIFT" when clicking. Then go to edit mode so the scene will look like this...

[image]

4. Now use the **Knife Project** as "rectangled" on the image below. The 1st triangle will get a new topology because of that knife-cut (circled green) on all places needed. **Its importand to look from top when cutting because this function is VIEW-DEPENDENT!**

[image]

5. In object mode **select both objects and join them together** using "CTRL + J" and enter edit mode. We have to **move all the point into the same height** and to do this we simply **make the height ZERO**. Select all points and hit "S" then "Z" and then "0" (ZERO on the numpad) and "ENTER". The scene should look like here...

[image]

6. Now You select **only the vertices of the 2nd triangle** in edit mode. Hit "X" and select **Only Edges & Faces** option so the **points will stay in place** like here...

[image]

7. You have to **face-up the whole thing now so select 4 vertices at a time and make faces** using "F" key like on the image below...

[image]

8. Simply make all the necessary faces and **YOU ARE DONE MATE - CONGRATS!!!** Final object should look like this...

[image]

Thats all - hope it helps Buddy.

*(Please dont forget to ACCEPT ANSWER using checkmark if it suits You)*

Answer (score 0):

My way of doing this:

1. Create a triangle as shown above
2. Set Origin to the center of mass
3. Duplicate the triangle
4. Rotate the duplicate 180 deg around Y axis if your view is Front
5. Align the triangles
6. Use Knife Project and remove highlighted faces
7. Ctrl+J

Done