# Image is darker in render than in viewport

Tags: objects, error, render-layers

I used sunlight for the image. Still, the rendering is blacker, but not in the viewport. Some objects are black and some are normal. Attached are both views. Please help me to figure out the problem.

P.S. I am new to blender....

[image: Rendered image]

[image: Actual projectenter code here]

---

@moonboots Yes, the sun is enabled. I don't know where I went wrong. [image]

Comment: Are you sure that your lights are enabled for render (please show a screenshot of your Outliner)?

Comment: It's also look like, that some of your faces are overlapping or turned backward, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121429/overlapping-meshes. You can also post your .blend here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Try looking for incorrect normal and also try placing the scene inside of a cube, it may help.